# Virtual host redirection not working in apache

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, virtual-hosts

i have created a simple virtual domain http://team.xyz.ae
once i hit this URL i want to redirect this to `http://team.xyz.ae/users/login  but now its redirecting to`

```
http://team.xyz.ae/users/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/loginusers/login
```

this is what i have written to create a virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xyz/
    Redirect permanent / http://team.xyz.ae/users/login
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect, `Redirect` redirects any request starting with the given URL.

You probably want to use `RedirectMatch` instead:

```
RedirectMatch permanent "^/$" http://team.xyz.ae/users/login
```